# Operation with Psingle type in Delphi Xe works fine, but not in Delphi Rio

Tags: delphi

I'm compiling a function that worked correctly in delphi XE, but now compiling it in delphi Rio gives me the following error:
[dcc32 Error] sBuffer.pas (330): E2015 Operator not applicable to this operand type

```
//type of variables used:

Buffer: Psingle;
bufferPos: Cardinal;
fchannels: Cardinal;


function sbuffer.Ptrbegin: Psingle;
begin
     Result := (buffer + bufferPos * fchannels); //---> Error
end;
```

[dcc32 Error] sBuffer.pas (330): E2015 Operator not applicable to this operand type

Comment: Is `: =` a typo?

Comment: You have pointermath on in XE, off in Rio.

Answer (score 2):

You need to enable the [pointer math option](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Pointer_Math_(Delphi)):

```
{$POINTERMATH ON}
```

Comment: I have tried it and it works correctly.
Thank you.!!